# Change fonts for units in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

In the rules of typography for my language there is a rule, that units (only units, not numbers) should be displayed in *different* font than the rest of the text.  E.g. if all of the text has serif font, units should be in sans serif font.  It is pretty unclear from the manual if something like that could be achieved.

Also (this is perhaps breaking the rules, but it is waste of time and space post two so similar questions separately): siunitx displays `\SI{0.5}{\per\s}` as `0.5/s`.  This is wrong, ISO 80000 requires displaying `0.5 s$^{-1}$`.  I would like to have `{\m\per\s}` displayed as `m/s` and  `{\per\s}` as `s$^{-1}$`.  Is that possible?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just for information: what language is it? This rule seems quite peculiar.

Comment: Slovenian.  I was told so by my proofreader.

Comment: Did you see it in some book? Can you point to some source?

Comment: Maybe you ought to convey the information in the second paragraph directly to the package's author/maintainer (Joseph Wright) -- the more so as that paragraph seems wholly unconnected to the material introduced in the first.

Comment: Yes, proofreader showed me that rule in the book, that deals with formatting technical expressions.  It is more like set of directions from language and technical experts.

Comment: The second question is readily solved: `\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal}` which is the default, by the way. If you want generally `per-mode=symbol`, you can locally change the option: `\SI[per-mode=reciprocal]{2}{\per\s}` or, more simply, `\SI{2}{s^{-1}}`

Comment: OK, now I consulted ISO 80000 and it requires Roman fonts for both numbers and units.  Damn linguists.

Comment: egreg: yes, I use globally [per-mode=symbol].  I have hundreds of instances I should locally change...  Maybe [per-mode=symbol] should be automatically overridden in case of {/per/something}.  But this is more like suggestion for the author of the package, I guess.

Comment: @Pygmalion Have you tried `\sisetup{unit-text-rm=\sffamily, unit-math-rm=\mathsf}` for the font thing (highly unrecommendedly)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It works!  It's ugly like hell (because sans serif of the same size is larger than serif), but it works :)

Comment: @Pygmalion As Mico said before, the other topic is really something for the author. You can issue an enhancement issue at the [author’s GitHub account for `siunitx`](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues). There are already some tests for an empty numerator for other reasons, this shouldn’t be hard to implement.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel OK, I'll have a thought about that.  I just hate to create new account just to post one issue :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.