# Automatic per-mode switch from symbol to reciprocal

Tags: siunitx

Is there a way to make the `siunitx` package output a unit with a single slash using `per-mode=symbol` and fallback to `per-mode=reciprocal` when there is more than one slash?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\metre\per\second}            % would output 1 m/s
\SI{1}{\ampere\per\metre\per\second} % would output 1 A m-1 s-1
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can set the options for each command when you use it: `\SI[per-mode=symbol]{1}{\meter\per\second}`... I don't know an automatic way :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You got +1 from me for a perfect MWE :)

Comment: My question is quite similar to the second part of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135845/change-fonts-for-units-in-siunitx). I opened a new enhancement request on https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx.

Answer (score 3):

Not very automatic, but helpful if you have to write it many times. You can define a new unit like

```
\DeclareSIUnit\Ms{m/s}
```

and use it like

```
\SI{1}{\Ms}
```

whenever you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\Ms{m/s}
%\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\metre\per\second}            

\SI{1}{\Ms}            % would output 1 m/s

\SI{1}{\ampere\per\metre\per\second} % would output 1 A m-1 s-1
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you have other instances of such cases, you have to define one for each of them.