# siunitx \celsius font

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I am writing a lab manual and using `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` to set the font.

However, when using `siunitx` the`\celsius` unit does not change font. All other units (that I have so far used) use correct font, whereas `\celsius` seems to be `cmr`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{math-rm=\mathsf, text-rm=\sffamily}}
\newcommand{\cc}{\cm\cubed}
\sisetup{range-phrase= --}
\begin{document}

\SI{250}{\cc} of solution were refluxed at \SI{73}{\celsius}.
A \SI{20}{\cc} aliquot of a solution of acetic acid was titrated against a standardised solution of NaOH (\SI{0.48}{\mole\per\deci\metre\cubed}. An average titre of \SI{15.3}{\cc} was required.  

A solution was distilled ensuring only the fraction boiling from \SIrange{56}{58}{\celsius} was collected.

The fraction boiling in the range \SIrange{56}{58}{\degreeCelsius} was collected.%just to see if \degreeCelsius produces a different output to \celsius

\end{document}
```

I tried the following solution [Can I make siunitx commands use serif fonts like the rest of the math in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66713/can-i-make-siunitx-commands-use-serif-fonts-like-the-rest-of-the-math-in-beamer) as can be seen in the 4th line of the MWE but doesn't work.

I also tried this suggestion (adapted to my needs) in the comments by  Qrrbrbirlbel in [Change fonts for units in siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135845/change-fonts-for-units-in-siunitx) (effectively the same as above.)

Is this just a bug as the correct font is selected for my other units?

Or is this a standard for `\celsius`?

Comment: Until Joseph answers, a dirty trick is to use `\let\mathrm\mathsf`, `\celsius` is hardwired with a `\mathrm`

Comment: One can reset the definition with `math-celsius={{}^{\circ}\kern-\scriptspace \mathsf{C}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In v3 of `siunitx`, the control of printing tries harder to be consistent with what you'd type in manually. So here we want to set `text-family-to-math` to propagate the text family (`sf`) to math mode. That will automatically handle the degree sign with the updated standard settings:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-family-to-math}
\begin{document}
The fraction boiling in the range \qtyrange{56}{58}{\degreeCelsius} was collected.
\end{document}
```

---

Older answer for v2:

As Ulrike comments, a change to `math-celsius` seems needed here

```
\sisetup{math-celsius = {}^{\circ}\kern-\scriptspace C}
```

I think that looks better over all than the current definition: I'll probably change the standard setting.